# Pictures not showing up in search

Tags: user-profile-property, sharepoint-search

I think I have a permission issue.  I have succesfully synced pictures from AD to sharepoint user profiles.  When I do a people search I will get an X for the users pictures.  But once I authenticate into mysites then I will be able to see the pictures in the search.  Any ideas?  And thanks for the help in advance
[image: People search before going into mysites]

[image: Mysite showing image is their]

[image: People search after going into mysites]

Comment: check this one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/564b01af-606e-4170-a81d-4f67397cc1a3/sharepoint-2013-search-not-showing-user-profile-photo?forum=sharepointsearch

Comment: Ok I change that setting and running a full crawl now.  Thanks.  I will let you know what the results are.

Comment: ok I mapped it people:pictureurl, ran a full sync and I am still receving the X untill a user goes into mysites.  I am using ADFS 2.0 as my authentication.

Comment: can you get the URL from X mark...right click and then check the path/location where it is picking? are you using the Userprofile sync or ADI?

Comment: https://qmysource.ohiohealth.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/adb535_MThumb.jpg is the path. I am using userprofile sync to import the profiles from AD.

Comment: it is pointing to right image? i would compare both path one from search and one from MySite?

Comment: Both images are correct.  Once I actually go to mysites and authenticate into that application then I am able to see the image in search

Comment: may be permission issue, but i cant tell you? can you load the image directly into the browser using path

Comment: If i input that url it will sending me to ADFS to authenticate and once I am authenticated it will load the image.

Comment: Only ADFS authentication is configured for MySite or windows authnetication also there

Comment: also check this http://nikpatel.net/2014/06/09/adfs-2-0-saml-2-0-and-sharepoint-2013-limitations-issues-and-workarounds/

Comment: I have ADFS authentication and ntlm.  But I hide the option for using ntlm permission.

Comment: I think Clearly permission issues on the profile photo folder....for some reason it is not authenticating any request from search for folder

Comment: I would have to agree.  I think it has to deal with ADFS and having the two web application.  We have not made mysites public to the rest of the orginazation so normal users will not be going into mysites and authenticating into that application.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found was to enable cross domain for profile pictures.

```
asnp Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://intranet.contoso.com
$wa.CrossDomainPhotosEnabled = $true
$wa.Update()
```

I have to give credit to the website I found it on. http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-enabling-cross-domain-profile-pictures